# Quit Django Celery worker from within task

Tags: python, django, celery

From within a celery task (ie a Python function) I wish to be able to shutdown the entire celery worker - how can I do this?

(Platform is Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not very elegant, but this does the trick:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("pkill -9 -f 'celery worker'", shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```